# Firefox or Chrome extension to imitate Apple browser start (top sites) page

Tags: browser, browser-addons

Does anyone know an extension for Windows (for Firefox or Chrome) which changes the browser start page to look like the top sites page on Apple Safari, so that the top sites view will be concaved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the firefox extention
[FoxTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/foxtab/), the same as top sites with more features.

Comment: it's realy amazing, just take time to configure it